# Where in the PSR standards does it say to not have the variable name after the type declaration?

Tags: php, symfony, psr-2, psr-1

Can anyone advise where in the PSR standards docs it documents that there should be nothing after the variable type in class member variables?

I used [PHP CodeStyle Fixer](http://cs.sensiolabs.org/) by doing the following: `php-cs-fixer fix MyConsoleCommand.php`

...and it removed the variable from the docblock. I have been doing this for some time now and I believed this was correct and standards-compliant.

Can anyone confirm?

```
     /**
-     * @var SiteManager $siteManager
+     * @var SiteManager
      */
     private $siteManager;

     /**
-     * @var Registry $doctrine
+     * @var Registry
      */
     private $doctrine;
```

Comment: AFAIK PSR doesn't say anything about this... But it *is* redundant, so why keep it?

Comment: Most (if not all) rules for phpdoc are tagged *symfony* so I guess they come from that Framework style guide and not PSR. That's particularly true here: **phpdoc_var_without_name [symfony]**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default all the levels are on and this particulair behaviour comes from the sympfony standard

> phpdoc_var_without_name [symfony]
>   @var and @type annotations should not contain the variable name.

see https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer and search for  "phpdoc_var_without_name"

if you don't want to use the Symfony standard do

`php php-cs-fixer.phar fix MyConsoleCommand.php --level=psr2`

hope it helps